# how to prevent re sizing of buttons after release of auto filter in excel 2010 using vba

Tags: vba, excel, resize, excel-2010

I have an excel sheet with some buttons (each doing different functions) i have created an auto filter macro as shown below but the problem is when i release the filter my all buttons get very small in their sizes (means they change their original size) although i selected the radio button (Do not move or size with cell) from each button's property.

```
Sub AutoFilter()

Range("A1:I1628").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$I$1631").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="="
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Blank Names").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

End Sub

I am badly in need of help, please assist me with this issue.plzzzzzz

Comment: does this problem occur when you change your screen resolution?

Comment: Thanks @blckbird for your quick turn around, No when i release the filter the buttons change their size...

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you need to set the object positioning of the button to "Don't move or size with cells" (as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mamhu.jpg), unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to post images yet).

If you have many different buttons in many different spreadsheets, this code should set the property for all of them (provided none of the worksheets are protected, etc.)

```
Sub test()
  Dim ws As Worksheet, sh As Shape

  For Each ws In Worksheets
    For Each sh In ws.Shapes
      If sh.Type = msoFormControl Then
        sh.Placement = xlFreeFloating
      End If
    Next
  Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and couldn't find a solution anywhere in the internet. Then on manual testing, I found that the issue is with the format.

- Please clear the format from the range of cells where you're trying to put autofilter

For example, I copied data from source file and pasted the as values and then I put the autofilter.